# Running Ruby with Homebrew but cannot get Bundler to Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, homebrew, bundler

Running `bundle install` I get the error: "-bash: bundle: command not found"

I can install Bundler with `gem install bundler` and I get no errors. In fact, if I run `gem list` it shows `bundler (1.14.6)`. However, `bundle -v` or anything like that doesn't work.

I have uninstalled bundler and re-installed.

`gem env` returns:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/mike/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /Users/mike/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/bin/ruby
     - /usr/local/bin/gem
```

`brew doctor` says "Your system is ready to brew"

`echo $PATH` says `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/bin/ruby:/usr/local/bin/gem`

`which gem` returns: /usr/local/bin/gem

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be a solution to your current issue, it is an alternative that could help you down the road in developing in Ruby / Rails.

I'd recommend moving to a ruby version control system such as [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) where you then have full control over your ruby version on a per-project basis. It's much easier than playing with your system Ruby on OS X too. You'll probably find that once you have one of these installed, your bundler issues disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a little bit late answer, but I was able to do it like this:

```
gem install bundler -n /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.5/bin
```

Where `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.5/bin` is a path where homebrew ruby installation gems is located